# Awk: expanding first field along the column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a task which requires some awk scripting:

Lets say I have a file:

```
A,under1
,under2
,under3
,under4
,under5
B,new1
,new2
,new3
C,sm1
,sm2
```

How could I make it look like this using awk?

```
A,under1
A,under2
A,under3
A,under4
A,under5
B,new1
B,new2
B,new3
C,sm1
C,sm2
```

In other words, I want to expand first field along the column.

Comment: Regarding pros and cons of setting `awk` variables as command paramaters *vs.* as command ooptions, see: [Are there 2 ways to set awk vars via command line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34255/2343).   The `-v`(option) syntax was introduced to deal with potential pitfalls of the paramater method shown in the two (current) answers.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
$ awk -F, '!$1{$1=p;}$1{p=$1;}1' OFS=, file
```

`$1{p=$1;}` When $1 has a value, store it in a variable p

`!$1` Mean $1 is empty. When $1 is empty, set $1 with p which contains the last $1 value.

`1` to print every line.

Comment: It is just what I was searching for. Thanks very much!

Comment: `!$1` does **not** _only_ mean _$1 is empty_. You should change it to `$1 == ""` or otherwise, you may have issues if the first field may be for instance `0`

Comment: @user30422 If this answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted and/or upvote it instead of posting a thank you comment. That is the way thanks are expressed on SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

another solution:

```
awk -F, '{$1=$1?P=$1:P;print}' OFS=,
```

sets `P` to $1 if $1 not empty. sets $1 to previous `P` otherwise